# How can I pipe console output to an ASP.NET page as it appears?

Tags: c#, asp.net, console

I'd like to run a console program from an ASP.NET page, pipe the output into a label or some other control, and have it updated dynamically as each `Console.Writeline` happens.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture standard output from another program with the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) class: set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true, and then read the programs output from the `StandardOutput` property.

The data you read can be used for whatever purpose you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Run the console app as a part of a web service (WCF with XML or JSON) and refresh periodically using [`ASP.NET AJAX`](http://www.asp.net/ajax/). This way, data transfer is minimal, a periodic query with occasional extra data in the reply.